# Getting the zynga scroller to work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, multi-touch

Has anyone ported the Zynga Scroller (https://github.com/zynga/scroller) to work in IE? It works exactly how I work like on canvas; pinch zoom, pan etc. But unfortunately it doesn't work in IE.